# How can I make Xenu Link Sleuth check relative URLs?

Tags: url, links, validation, relative-urls

I'm using an old free web crawler called Xenu Link Sleuth to find broken links on my site.

Normally it works well enough for my needs, but the site that I'm testing it on right now seems to exclusively use relative URLs and it appears that Xenu isn't following them.

Is there an option somewhere to fix that? I know that Xenu is pretty outdated, but relative links existed years ago as well, so surely Xenu has support for them.